Is Copula Modeling Suitable for Accounting for Temporal Dynamics in Olive Plantation Data?
I am working on a project analyzing olive plantation data, where I aim to simulate the relationship between investment costs (Costs), revenues (Revenues), and temperature (Temp) over time, accounting for the specific temporal dynamics of the data. The goal is to generate realistic scenarios for future tree plantations, calculate the IRR of the investment imposing conditions on the Temperature. My idea is to employ copulas.
The data I have consists of annual records for 10 years, where:

Costs represent the investments required for the olive plantation.
Revenues represent the returns from the sale of olives.
Temp is the annual average temperature.
TempCng is the annual temperature change.

Since the data is inherently temporal (i.e., Costs and Revenues are not independent and identically distributed over time), I aim to capture the time structure, particularly the significant initial investments (Costs), followed by revenues (Revenues) that only materialize after several years as the trees need time to grow. To address this, I include a time trend variable in my analysis.
Here’s my approach so far:
# Packages
library(VineCopula)
library(copula)

# Synthetic data for convenience
Costs <- c(100, 0, 150, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Revenues <- c(0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 225, 100, 0, 150, 5)
Temp <- c(20.00, 21.60, 16.05, 15.68, 17.40, 19.51, 19.87, 19.02, 18.21, 18.18)
TempCng <- c(0.001464764, diff(Temp) / head(Temp, -1))
Years <- seq(2008,2017)

# Create data frame
OliveTrees <- data.frame(Costs, Revenues, Temp, TempCng, row.names = Years)

# Compute mean and standard deviation
mu_C <- mean(Costs)
mu_R <- mean(Revenues)
mu_T <- mean(TempCng)

sigma_C <- sd(Costs)
sigma_R <- sd(Revenues)
sigma_T <- sd(TempCng)

# Normalize the data
OliveTrees$CNorm <- (OliveTrees$Costs - mu_C) / sigma_C
OliveTrees$RNorm <- (OliveTrees$Revenues - mu_R) / sigma_R
OliveTrees$TNorm <- (OliveTrees$TempCng - mu_T) / sigma_T

# Apply empirical distribution
C_dist <- pobs(OliveTrees$CNorm)
R_dist <- pobs(OliveTrees$RNorm)
T_dist <- pobs(OliveTrees$TNorm)

# Time trend (sequence of years)
S_dist <- pobs(1:nrow(OliveTrees))

# Combine the distributions
U <- cbind(C_dist, R_dist, T_dist, S_dist)

# Fit a Gaussian copula
CopulaModel <- normalCopula(dim = 4, dispstr = 'un')
FittedCopula <- fitCopula(CopulaModel, U, method = 'ml')
CopulaModel@parameters <- coef(FittedCopula)

# Simulate from the copula
set.seed(321)
U <- rCopula(n = nrow(OliveTrees), CopulaModel)

# Sort the simulated values to account for the time trend
U <- U[order(U[, 4]), ]

# Apply the inverse CDF to get the simulated values
C_sim <- quantile(OliveTrees$CNorm, U[, 1])
R_sim <- quantile(OliveTrees$RNorm, U[, 2])
T_sim <- quantile(OliveTrees$TNorm, U[, 3])

# Denormalize the simulated values
C_sim <- round(C_sim * sigma_C + mu_C, 2)
R_sim <- round(R_sim * sigma_R + mu_R, 2)
T_sim <- T_sim * sigma_T + mu_T

# Create a data frame for the simulation results
OliveTrees_sim <- data.frame(C_sim, R_sim, T_sim, row.names = Years)
OliveTrees_sim$Temp <- round(OliveTrees$Temp[1] * c(1, cumprod(1 + OliveTrees_sim$T_sim[2:length(OliveTrees_sim$T_sim)])), 2)

My Questions:

Is this copula approach valid for accounting for the temporal dynamics of olive plantation data? Specifically, temporal dynamics refer to the fact that there are large initial costs followed by growing revenues, and that both are not IID due to the time structure.

Is including a time trend (in the form of a sequence of years) a suitable solution for modeling the temporal dependencies?

Is there any literature or research that supports this approach, or are there better ways to model the temporal dependency in the data?

Are there any better modeling approaches or improvements that could better capture the temporal dynamics between Costs, Revenues, and Temperature?


Thank you for your help!

This is a refreshing topic! I don't pretend to be an expert on this (far from it), but using copulas is not an unreasonable approach. But if you're going to include temperature, shouldn't you also include rainfall / rainfall change?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about quantitative finance as usually understood on this site. However, it could be a good question for Cross Validated Stack Exchange.

Dear @RichardHardy maybe it is not clear from the question but since I have costs and revenues I want to calculate and simulate the IRR of my investment making scenarios about the temperature. To me this is a financial problem of conditional expected value of not independent random variables.

I see your point, but my experience in this site is that these kind of questions are not considered on topic. Nothing against your question per se, my point is only about its fit on this site.

It's important to understand the actual physical processes that you're trying to model, i.e. the underlying agricultural product, and I've seen some very complicated models for that. We all remember what happened when people, not understanding what they were doing, tried to re-use the gaussian copula, widely used in life insurance, to corporate credit. :) For example, in addition to the temperature, does the variability of precipitation matter? Do catastrophes like storms, forest fires, or plant diseases matter? (Not really looking for answers, just pointing out what one should consider)
